# Android ProgressBar not update when file downloading

Tags: android, progress-bar

I create a Android service to download music (.mp3) to sdcard, before download I call startUpdateProgress and when download finished I call stopUpdateProgress(), and using Handle to send status broadcast to Activity to set progress for ProgressBar. But it is not working, when download finished, ProgressBar is update to 100%.

Please tell me why? Thank you!

Comment: Please give us code? Thank you!

Comment: Better try AsyncTask to do this job, more stable and it's working, I did it before.